# Can Biztalk use a remote MSQL server in a different domain without a trust relationship?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, active-directory, biztalk

I have a remote MSQL instance that I want to use with biztalk.  My machine running biztalk cannot join the same domain as the MSSQL instance, nor can we create a trust relationship between the two windows domains.

Is there a way to configure biztalk to authenticate?  Username/password (like any other DB would use) would be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about using the SQL Server as the primary data tier for your BizTalk installation, then maybe.  There's an old trick where you create local accounts on both servers with the sam credentials (id & password) and then use the local account for your services.  This is hacky and not reccomended.

As far as the SQL Server Adapter, just provide the credentials in the conneciton string.  Caould be a SQL Account or a remote domain account.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the primary data tier.  I'll try the trick tomorrow.